# Parsing XML with multiple namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, xml-namespaces

I have XML in the following form that I want to parse with PHP (I can't change the format of the XML). Neither SimpleXML nor DOM seem to handle the different namespaces - can anyone give me sample code? The code below gives no results.

```
    <atom:feed>
        <atom:entry>
            <atom:id />
            <otherns:othervalue />
        </atom:entry>
        <atom:entry>
            <atom:id />
            <otherns:othervalue />
        </atom:entry>
    </atom:feed>



    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($url);
    $entries = $doc->getElementsByTagName("atom:entry");
    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        $id = $entry->getElementsByTagName("atom:id");
        echo $id;
        $othervalue = $entry->getElementsByTagName("otherns:othervalue");
        echo $othervalue;
    }
```

Comment: `SimpleXMLElement->children`, or `DOMElement::getElementsByTagNameNS ( string $namespaceURI , string $localName )` (which would be the uri defined by `atom`, and `entry` without the `atom:` prefix), and please, just for the hell of it, find one of the hundreds of similar questions here on SO. This is NOT a new question by a long shot.

Comment: just `$doc->getElementsByTagName("entry");` The keyword in the manual is *local name*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want to post with an answer to this awful question. Sorry.

Namespaces are irrelavent with DOM - I just wasn't getting the nodeValue from the Element.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);
$feed = $doc->getElementsByTagName("entry");
foreach($feed as $entry) {
    $id = $entry->getElementsByTagName("id")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $id;
    $id = $entry->getElementsByTagName("othervalue")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $othervalue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to register your name spaces. Otherwise simplexml will ignore them.
This bit of code I got from the PHP manual and I used in my own project

```
$xmlsimple = simplexml_load_string('YOUR XML'); 
$namespaces = $xmlsimple->getNamespaces(true);
$extensions = array_keys($namespaces);

foreach ($extensions as  $extension )
{
    $xmlsimple->registerXPathNamespace($extension,$namespaces[$extension]);
}
```

After that you use xpath on $xmlsimple